# iPhone keeps disconnecting & connecting when transferring data

Tags: iphone, usb, xcode

I have a MacBook Pro (2015), and an iPhone 7 Plus.

The problem is the following: If the iPhone is connected to my Mac, then whenever I run an app via XCode, or the Mac is just transferring data, the iPhone starts disconnecting and connecting (the battery icon indicates it), and the data transfer fails.

---

First I thought that this was a cable issue, because If I adjust the cable in a certain position then it works, but I realized that it is not:

because

- I bought brand new cables
- I cleaned the USB port of the Mac

But still nothing

It is really annoying.

---

Sometimes it gets fixed if I unplug & reinsert the USB like 5-7 times.

Comment: I have a feeling that your USB port has a *physical problem*.  This [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/296977/119271) has more details on this.  You can test this by connecting a USB drive and attempting to transfer large amounts of data to/from the drive.  If it fails, it's the port.

Comment: I ALWAYS experience this, and I know many fellow people who experience this. You are not alone in this issue. I may think it is a problem with either the the cords as a whole or hardware. I would love to hear from someone who was had this problem and solved it. Also, I have an iPhone 6s and a MacBook Air.

Comment: This question had some helpful answers: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/298573/45492

Answer (score 4):

1. Disconnect your iPhone or iPad.
2. Open Terminal and type

```
sudo killall -STOP -c usbd
```

3. Happily connect again your devices.

Comment: 1 year later but I still have the same issue with the latest macOS, latest ios, latest devices, new cables...

Comment: Work like magic

Answer (score 1):

Tried really everything, the only thing that works is charging my iPhone to 100%, than the iPhone 11 or 8 does not disconnect anymore from my Mid 2015 Macbook. So and hoc connecting is a problem, as well as charging your phone via the laptop.